# How to get a latest row for each ID based on a timestamp

Tags: r, date

I need rows with latest time values for each group. I have multiple rows and columns. The input data looks like:

```
view(DF)

ID  Value1  Value2  Value3  Value4  Time
1   1   7   13  19  2013-11-15 21:12:03:337
1   2   8   14  20  2013-12-23 15:12:01:227
2   3   9   15  21  2014-12-07 14:37:01:127
2   4   10  16  22  2013-12-12 05:23:01:239
3   5   11  17  23  2011-12-25 15:12:01:227
3   6   12  18  24  2011-12-25 15:12:02:227
```

I need the results like:

```
ID  Value1  Value2  Value3  Value4  Time
1   2   8   14  20  2013-12-23 15:12:01:227
2   3   9   15  21  2014-12-07 14:37:01:127
3   6   12  18  24  2011-12-25 15:12:02:227
```

I've already reviewed the solution available on community.rstudio.com/t/replacing-all-null-values-in-a-dataset-code-issue/11285

I tried

```
DF_filter = DF%>% 
  group_by(ID) %>%
  slice(which.max(Time))
```

Also , I tried to convert time column in timestamp by

```
DF_time <- strptime(x=as.character(DF$Time), format = "%y-%m-%d %H%M:S")
```

But DF_time is returning `NA`

The first code is returning a data (`DF_filter`) having 0 obs. and 6 variables.
Please help.

Comment: You can sort by date then use `last` from dplyr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a `data.table` approach

**sample data**

```
DT <- fread('ID  Value1  Value2  Value3  Value4  Time
1   1   7   13  19  "2013-11-15 21:12:03:337"
            1   2   8   14  20  "2013-12-23 15:12:01:227"
            2   3   9   15  21  "2014-12-07 14:37:01:127"
            2   4   10  16  22  "2013-12-12 05:23:01:239"
            3   5   11  17  23  "2011-12-25 15:12:01:227"
            3   6   12  18  24  "2011-12-25 15:12:02:227"', quote = "\"")
```

**code**

```
#first, set miliseconds correct by replacing the last : with a .
DT[, Time := gsub( "(.*)(:)([0-9]*$)", "\\1.\\3", Time)]
#now convert to POSIXct
DT[, Time := as.POSIXct( Time, format = " %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")]

#now, pull the max Time per group
DT[DT[, .I[which.max(Time)], by=ID]$V1]
```

**output**

```
#    ID Value1 Value2 Value3 Value4                Time
# 1:  1      2      8     14     20 2013-12-23 15:12:01
# 2:  2      3      9     15     21 2014-12-07 14:37:01
# 3:  3      6     12     18     24 2011-12-25 15:12:02
```

Comment: This works but I don't why but it's missing one row. For e.g. the filtered data should have to 2560 rows(when calculated using  @clemsang's comment on the original question), but using your code, I am getting 2559 rows.

Comment: You should get one row per unique `ID`. So check `length(unique(DF$ID))`. What does it return?

Answer (score 2):

After formatting Time variable correctly:

Using `base`:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(
  split(df, df$ID),
  function(x) x[which.max(x$Time), ]
))
```

Alternatively:

```
merge(aggregate(Time ~ ID, data = df, FUN = max), df)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DF_filter <- DF %>% 
  inner_join((DF %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarise(Time=max(Time))),
             by=c('ID'= 'ID', 'Time' = 'Time'))
```